# Передача данных между test case

Tags: тестирование

Использую groovy Для тестирования.

Задача такая: есть `test case` в нём `test step` с переменной, в которой есть данные.

Нужно, чтоб данные из переменной записались в `properties` , которые находятся в другом `test case`.

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2):

Вы не правильно готовите тесты! Тесты должны быть между собою независимыми!
Есть две ситуации, когда между ними существует что-то общее так:

1. Начальное состояние, тогда это пишется в setUp()-подобных методах
2. Действия по очистке, тогда это пишется в tearDown()-подобных методах.